# system updates not installing upon reboot

Tags: updates, horus

Running Horus 7.1, I just download the lastest system updates in AppCenter and then restarted when asked, but that just brought me back to my login screen without installing them. After a few minutes it asks me to restart again, but it still doesn't install anything. What do I do now?

Comment: On about the 4th reboot, the updates finally installed, but upon rebooting from that, the boot loader went into emergency mode. Turning the machine off and on got it back up, apparently working normally. Unnerving.

Comment: Or so I thought. AppCenter kept failing to install the remaining updates with "Update All", but I was able to install most of them one-by-one. But it fails on Runtimes and Vim; refreshing and repairing didn't help ... and then AppCenter crashed.

Comment: Aborted due to failure (While pulling runtime/org.freedesktop.Sdk/x86_64/23.08 from remote flathub: Server returned status 404: Not Found)